# Issues with table formatting

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am having some difficulties formatting a table I am creating. I am wanting my `<th>` to go the full width of the table and both `<tr>`'s. Also even though I have my first `<td>` set to 200px for width, it is going over as much as my `<th>`.

https://jsfiddle.net/bL47ro78/

How can I get..

```
 <th class="view_topic_th">
    <td>Date</td>
</th>
```

To be as wide as my table and `<tr?`'s.

Comment: `<th>` is the head equivalent of a `<td>` not a `<tr>`. E.g. it should be `<tr class="view_topic_th"><th>Date</th></tr>`. And then you can add `colspan="2"` to your `<th>` if you want it to be 2 columns wide.

Comment: I am running this through a loop and for some reason my first table has that <tr> only going to the first <td> section?

Comment: Never mind, I just had to put a columnspan in. Thanks!

Comment: @joshhunt Now it is doing this, except that th has a border..https://jsfiddle.net/bL47ro78/2/

Comment: @Paul check  this https://jsfiddle.net/bL47ro78/5/ . is that what you need?

Comment: @RojalinSahoo Yes, but the borders collapsing.

Comment: is this ok https://jsfiddle.net/bL47ro78/6/

Comment: @RojalinSahoo What if I have this as the current `<th>`? `<tr class="view_topic_th">
     <th class="view_topic_th_left"><?php echo  $post_date; ?></th>
     <th colspan='2'></th>
     <th colspan='1' class="view_topic_th_right"><?php echo "#" . $count2; ?></th>
    </tr>` How could I convert that? The two classes are containers to assign margins.

Comment: you can do like https://jsfiddle.net/bL47ro78/8/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87226/discussion-between-rojalin-sahoo-and-paul).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution that may help you to format your table:

```
<table class="forum_view_topic_table"> 
    <tr calss="view_topic_th">
            <th class="view_topic_th_left" align="right">Date</th> 
            <th class="view_topic_th_right">Count</th> 
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width='200' valign='top' align='center' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>User Info Here!</td>
        <td valign='top' style='border: 1px solid #000000'>
            <div style='min-height: 125px;'>Post 1
                <br />by John Smith
                <hr />Content</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2'>
            <hr />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bL47ro78/10/